# Actionscript 3.0 Loading swf file into flash project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading

http://tinypic.com/r/9i8hi0/7

It's a video showing you my problem.
I don't know why the swf file won't work in the flash
I used loader to put the swf file into the stage but it doesn't do it.
I plays fine when I just open the swf file in Flash Pro CS-4 but when I put it into a flash, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to Publish Settings [Ctrl+Alt+F12] -> Flash -> Enable Debugging. This will at least show you the line where the error occurs, but remember to disable it before deploying (it adds a few kilobytes).

The video doesn't show enough to be sure, so here are a few wild guesses:

0) The error is not related to the loaded swf (the Enable Debugging setting will help a lot with this one).

1) Somewhere in the code not shown you tried to access a property from the loaded swf that was not available.

2) The loaded swf contains code that depends on the stage or root property and is erroneously accessing the main stage/root, where the needed property couldn't be found (enable debugging in the loaded swf to check this one, it shows the line even for loaded code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the complete HTTP path to your swf file such as:

```
decoder.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/site/decoder.swf"));
```

Comment: If that was the case I think it would throw a different error, along the lines of "could not load". Unless he has two different versions of the loaded swf in different paths, but that is unlikely.

Comment: The error message states that there may be a null reference causing the trouble. I though that maybe it was due to decoder not being created correctly. But you are right, using Enable Debugging is the best way to go +1.